# C++ Compilation window contains junk characters

Tags: c++, emacs

I am compiling c++ program using emacs.  In the compilation window, I get junk characters.   Example given below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()   
{   
 error

}
```

I am compiling this inside emacs by using compile command as

```
g++  error.cpp
```

In the compilation window, I get the following error.

```
g++ error.cpp 
error.cpp: In function âint main()â:
error.cpp:10:3: error: âerrorâ was not declared in this scope
error.cpp:12:1: error: expected â;â before â}â token

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Wed Jan 23 17:09:17
```

As you can notice there are some junk characters in the window ( Many of the junks are disappeared during pasting! ).  How can avoid this? .  I don't see the issue if I do the compilation in a  terminal.

I am using emacs 24.1.1 in ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Can you show the value of variable `(describe-variable 'default-process-coding-system)`?

Comment: looks like iso/utf encoding problem...

Comment: The value of (describe-variable 'default-process-coding-system) is        " default-process-coding-system is a variable defined in `C source code'.
    Its value is (iso-latin-1-unix . iso-latin-1-unix)

    Documentation:
    Cons of coding systems used for process I/O by default.
    The car part is used for decoding a process output,
    the cdr part is used for encoding a text to be sent to a process."

Comment: Its value is (iso-latin-1-unix . iso-latin-1-unix)

Comment: Try to setup
`(setq default-process-coding-system '(utf-8-unix . utf-8-unix))`

Comment: @artscan - Thanks.  The issue is solved with the setting that you have mentioned. I don't see junk characters now.

Answer (score 1):

In many locales, the gcc compiler emits the character `â` when it intended to emit a single quote character (why it does this, I have no clue).

Try setting the locale to the default `C` locale.

Comment: The issue is solved. See the comment from artscan above. Thanks!.